# How to evaluate certain recursive function for 2 variables?

Tags: functions, recursion

Recently, I was working on a certain recursive formula in 2 variables which I was able to simplify to the below
$$F(x,y;p)=1+pF(x-1,y;p)+(1-p)F(x+1,y;p)$$
with $p$ being some real constant parameter with $p\in(0,1)$.

However, I have been having trouble solving for the definition of $F$ from here. I have the boundary condition that $F(x,y;p)=0$ for $x=\pm y$. I also know that $F(x,y;\frac{1}{2})=y^2-x^2$.

Given that I have not been able to proceed beyond this, is there a general solution for $F(x,y;p)$ for all $p\in(0,1)$?

Comment: Note that only one variable (namely $x$) is involved in the recurrence relation, so that $a_n := F(n,y;p)$ should satisfy $a_n = 1 + pa_{n-1} + (1-p)a_{n+1}$. It is an inhomogeneous second-order linear recurrence with constant coefficients, which can be solved the "standard" method, i.e. by studying its characteristic equation & finding a particular solution (e.g. with an ansatz).

Comment: Note too that you can pick *any* function (even a strongly discontinuous one) for $F(x, y; p)$ on $x\in[0,2)$, and any $y, p$, such that $F$ satisfies your conditions, then use the method described by Abezhiko to extend that uniquely to all $x$. I.e., if you were intending to find $F$ for all $x,y,p$ from the information given, there are uncountably many solutions.